# Powerpoint VBA - Error when trying to delete slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint, slide

I am trying to delete slides in a PowerPoint presentation but it is giving me the error:

[image: Method ".Delete" of object "_slide" failed]

Once this error comes up it does not even allow me to manually delete the slides, it gives this error message and I have to close the presentation and reopen:
[image] 
(even when I press the stop button in vba it gives the same message)

The code is below

```
For i = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
    If  ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = False Then    
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Delete
    End If
Next
```

Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: The code works fine for me. Are you able to remove the slides manually before running macro?

Comment: Yes, before running the code there are no issues

Comment: I believe the issue is not with code but due to some bug in installation.

Comment: I've tried it on different machines and it's giving the same issue for some reason

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code. Do you get this message on every presentation you try it on, or just on one file?

Comment: The full code loops through multiple files, this error starts appearing randomly after the 3rd or 4th file (I've tried different files too) and then it just becomes more frequent. I have managed to find a workaround though, If I save a copy of the ActivePresentation and work on that then it's fine. Not sure why that works though, but it's solved the issue at hand